# Java - Array of Coordinates

Tags: java, arrays, coordinates, nested-loops

I need to write an single array of coordinates. I have written the Coordinate class such that:

```
public class Coordinate {
   int row;
   int column;

   public Coordinate (int column, int row) {
   ...
   }
}
```

In my main method, I want to have an array `Coordinate positions[] = new Coordinate[64]` and populate it with values (0,0), (0,1), ..., (7,6), (7,7).

Any idea on how to approach this? I have tried nested loops but I can't get it right.

EDIT: sorry guys, still trying to figure things out with Stack Overflow
I am doing:

```
  for(int i=0; i<64; i++) {
        for(int c=0; c<8; c++) {
            for(int r=0; r<8; r++) {
            positions[i] = new Coordinate(c, r);
            }
        }
      }
```

But its making a mess and looping way too much

Comment: post your best nested loop attempt

Comment: for(int i=0; i<64; i++) { for(int c=0; c<8; c++) {for(int r=0; r<8; r++) { positions[i] = new Coordinate(c, r);}}} // But it's not working cause it's looping over and over and I get this hudge array

Comment: Post it in your question, not in a comment, please.

Comment: @M.Bris please add the main method to the question via edit... it will be much harder to read in the comments

Comment: How do you add elements to the array? Is it something like this: `arr[i] = new Coordinate(0,0)`?

Comment: Yous should probably try hand executing that code, it's got some pretty obvious errors.  Look up "hand execution" with Google and read up.

Comment: @markspace what are the obvious errors?

Comment: Well, the outer loop runs 64 times, the inner loop runs 8 times 64, and the loop inside that runs 64 times 8 times 8.  Obviously not going to work.

Comment: You are using too many nested loops. You don't need loop for `i`. Instead create that variable once and increment it after each assignment. You can add `i=i+1` after `positions[i] = new Coordinate(c, r);` or use rewrite it as `positions[i++] = new Coordinate(c, r);`. Otherwise your inner loops will need to iterate on [0]-th element (leaving there lastly assigned element which will be Coordinate(7, 7)), then [1] and again (7,7) will be set there, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looping too much because of your first loop , a simple solution would go like this :

```
int i=0;
 for(int c=0; c<8; c++) {
        for(int r=0; r<8; r++) {
        positions[i] = new Coordinate(c, r);
        i++; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand as well what you want to do. First of all if you want to store different type of coordinates you can use this

```
public class Coords<T> {

  private final  T x;
  private final T y;

  public Coords(T x,T y ) {
    this.y = y;
    this.x = x;
  }
}
```

then it depends of the rule if you want to follow. As i understand you want maybe you want something like this

```
        int count = 0;
        for( int i = 0;i < max_first_value; i++)
        {
            for(int o=0;o<max_second_value; o++){
                if(count == 64){
                    i=max_first_value;
                    o=max_second_value;
                    break;
                }
                positions[count] = new Coord<Integer>(i,o);
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Where max_fist_value and max_second_values are the max value that you want for your coordinates but it depens on what rule you want to use to fill this array. The variable count are is used to not exceed the bound of the array